# There is no SDK with the name or path 'iphoneos2.0'

Tags: iphone, ios

I keep getting this error.

> There is no SDK with the name or path 'iphoneos2.0'

I am running some templates at 
http://appsamuck.com/day1.html

I'm running the latest sdk, in the pop up menu (simulator) there is an option iPhone Device 2.0 (missing) (Base SDK)

Comment: Is iPhone OS 2.0 even supported any more?  The current release is 3.1, and 3.2 for the iPad, and 4.0 beta 2 SDK is out.

Answer (score 3):

Then just select another SDK: 3, 3.2 or 4.
Most examples will work, even if they were prepared for SDK 2.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, i have just met this problem last night :) I think your project write in xCode 3.2.2 or earlier but you try to run it on xCode 3.2.3. And you need to tell xCode to run your app in iPhone Simulator with iOS 4 (iPhone running iOS 4 can run iPhone's app write for iOS 3). If that's your problem do some step to slove it:

1. Select "Project" menu on xCode.
2. Select "Edit Project Settings" submenu.
3. Look at line "Base SDK for All Configurations", select iPhone Simulator 4.0 (May be it look like disable but you can select).
4. Run your project to compile your project.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code here, it's one of the very first iPhone dev tutorials written, and it's evidently not been updated to reflect the current SDK and Xcode versions.

I would suggest starting with a more modern tutorial, then coming back to this once you have the confidence to be able to understand and fix the code.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the project

project> Edit project Setting

Change BASE SDK to the latest IOS

after that

Code Signing Identity: Change it to DON'T CODE SIGN

after doing this some of my applications was working fine but not all of them.